# Creating an INDEX to improve slow execution time caused by ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing, phpmyadmin

I have the following query in a PHP function. This gets called a number of times depending on a number of factors, but even if it is executed only 1 time it takes a long time.

```
SELECT  `date` as dateTo
FROM    table_name tbl
WHERE    `colA` = 223 and `colB` <> 1
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The database table has about 2 million records and the `ORDER BY` is slowing the execution time.

What is the best `INDEX` I could have in this scenario?

Would an index on `date` only be beneficial or would I have to include `colA` and `colB`?

### -----

I ended up using this query,

```
SELECT  `ColA`,`date`, `ColB`
FROM  atm_status_log
WHERE  `ColA` = 223
HAVING  `ColB` <> 1
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

and this `INDEX`, `INDEX(colA, colB, date)`

Comment: What index exists currently?

Comment: The best  index  is a multi column index on `INDEX(date, colA, colB)`   please note the index should order the columns the way i said.

Comment: How many rows would get selected and need sorting?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The table is ordered by descending order so all the records are sorted.

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you add the comment as an answer I will select it.

Comment: No it should only sort the selected rows. It does not sort the whole table and then select from the sorted list

Comment: It selects the date that ColB was last different that 1 (1 may be a different value)

Comment: @Galeaettu Done ive posted mine comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a index on date, colA, colB.
Please keep in mind the order off that index matters.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD KEY index_name (date, colA, colB);
```

Comment: Starting a composite index with a column to compared as a range, or to be used in the `ORDER BY`, is almost always sub-optimal.  Starting with `date` lets the Optimizer use the index for `ORDER BY`, but not for filtering on `colA`.  One mitigating factor is that it is a "covering index" because it contains all the columns needed for the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add index for colA and colB. That will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT `date` as dateTo
FROM table_name tbl
WHERE `colA` = 223 and `colB` <> 1
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

One approach to indexing would be `table_name(colA, colB, date)`.  This is a covering index for the query.  However, it will not eliminate the sorting.

You *could* try this approach:

```
SELECT dateTo
FROM (SELECT `date` as dateTo, colB
      FROM table_name tbl
      WHERE `colA` = 223 
      ORDER BY `date` DESC
     ) t
WHERE `colB` <> 1;
```

The subquery should be able to make use of a query on `table_name(colA, date)`.  It will need to materialize the entire result set, but then choosing `colB <> 1` should be pretty fast.  I'm not thrilled with this approach, because it assumes that the subquery remains ordered when read by the outer query -- but that is true in MySQL.

Comment: the second approach did improve the execution time thanks, I will try the index as well.

Answer (score 1):

How many different value in `colB`?  If it can have only `0` and `1`, then change the filter to

```
colB = 0
```

and add this

```
INDEX(colA, colB, date)
```

(The `date` must be last, but A and B can be in either order.)  Only then can the all the filtering and the `ORDER BY` be handled by the `INDEX`.

If colB has more than 2 values, then let's slightly improve on Gordon's solution:

```
SELECT  `date` as dateTo
    FROM  table_name tbl
    WHERE  `colA` = 223
      AND   colB <> 1
    ORDER BY  `date` DESC;
```

with `INDEX(colA, colB, date)`, with the columns in exactly that order.  This index would be a "covering" index.

Comment: The `HAVING` needs to be before the `ORDER BY`. Would the index in that case be `INDEX(colA, colB, date)` ?

Comment: The index worked( `INDEX(colA, colB, date)` ) and it is much faster. Thank you.

Comment: My bad.  Fixed my answer.  Then, `HAVING` is no better (and probably worse) than `WHERE`, so folded colB test into `WHERE`.